# Add co-administrator to B2C tenant to mange the directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Could you please let me know, How we can be able to added the co-administrator or my colleague to the newly created B2C tenant as a Global admin.

I’m struggling to find the way out. I have gone through some article were it point to add/import the user from external Azure active directory as source using classic portal.

Scenario is: I’ve created the B2C tenant were I marked as GA. I want my colleague to manage the directory in my absence.

Have followed the guide to assign Admin Roles to a User in Azure AD. On the Step 5, select the Global Administrator under Directory Role

Still not able to connect through Powershell

Answer (score -1):

> Still not able to connect through Powershell

Do you mean your colleague can't use his Azure AD account to login your Azure AD with PowerShell?  With this command `Connect-AzureAD`?

We can **via Azure classic portal** to add Global Admin role to your colleague's account, like this:
[image]

After that, we can use PowerShell to login your Azure AD with `-TenantId`, like this:

`connect-azuread -TenantId 0e0a9c5d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx375bxxxx`

[image]

============================
**Update**:

If you want make your account can login new azure portal, we should grant your account admin permission of this subscription, we can set this here:

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I was able to login through the Powershell but unable to retrieve the user's. Also tried access the portal, getting the error msg

"User authorization failed. You must be a Global Administrator in f0967b88-c7ea-432e-a269-33d738507967 in order to access this functionality. If you created this B2C directory just now, please try again after couple of minutes.Read the following article to learn more."

Comment: Additional info regarding the current scenario, the person who had created the B2C has moved out and i'm the new person. I have requested for the access to the subscription owner to grant me the right. He have me  as owner from portal to the B2C tenant.

Comment: @KarthikNeel Do you want to set your account as the global admin of this subscription? or just manage some resources of this subscription?  set your account can login the Azure portal?

Comment: @KarthikNeel I have update my answer, we can follow those steps to grant admin permission to your account, please check my answer.

Comment: @KarthikNeel Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Let add few more point for clarity, This is a separate tenant(test.onmicrosoft.com) created for manage identity of external user those who access the Web app. This was created by user A. He left the organisation, now B need access. I dont want to create a new account for him in this tenant. Grant him access with company ID(user@company.com).

Comment: Yes, i've managed to connect the B2C with the help of Invite the geust user and we not able to create additional user attribute via portal